# Prove that the limit of sequence $x(n) = (2^n/n!)$ is $0$ using definition of sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Generally we solve questions of this $n!$ form by finding a relation between numerator and denominator.

Example - $n^2/n!$ was easily solved by using 
$n^2/n! <= n^2/n(n-1)(n-2)$

Is there such a relation b/w n! and 2^n?

In the hint, we are told to use $x(n) = (2^n/n!) <= 2(2/3)^{(n-2)}$, which is something we can easily prove by PMI and thus prove the statement. But how did we come up with it? What general relation between n! and 2^n was used?

Edit : Please solve this using the definition of convergence of sequence only. It's given in this manner.

Comment: Think about $n!$ (a product of $n$ numbers, almost all of them larger than $2$) and $2^n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use that
$$
\frac{x(n+1)}{x(n)}=\frac{2}{n+1}
$$
has the limit $0$, thus there is some $N$ such that this fraction is smaller $1/2$ or $2/3$ or whatever for $n\ge N$.

---

Or look strongly at
$$
\frac{2^n}{n!}=\frac21·\frac22·\frac23·\frac24···\frac2n
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate just a little? I didn't understand what you are saying. You are not attempting to use ratio test, right?

Comment: @Lelouch, if you understand the second thing that LutzL says then it is the proof of the given hint. After that it's just squeeze theorem.